pywintypes.com_error when running python code as Inventor API
def createEndOrCoffeeTable(length, width, height, legType, color):
    import win32com.client as wc

    inv =  wc.GetActiveObject('Inventor.Application')
    doc = inv.Documents.Add(12290, inv.FileManager.GetTemplateFile(12290, 8962))

    part_comp_def = doc.ComponentDefinition

    #Create table main geometry
    main = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.WorkPlanes.Item(3))
    main2 = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.WorkPlanes.Item(3))

    tg = inv.TransientGeometry

    twoprect1_len = length/2 #Dimensions, in cm
    twoprect1_wid = (height-10)/2

    twoprect2_len = length/2 - 10
    twoprect2_wid = (height-10)/2 - 10

    twoprect1 = main.SketchLines.AddAsTwoPointCenteredRectangle(tg.CreatePoint2d(0, 0), tg.CreatePoint2d(twoprect1_len, twoprect1_wid)) #Draw two point rectangles
    twoprect2 = main2.SketchLines.AddAsTwoPointCenteredRectangle(tg.CreatePoint2d(0, 0), tg.CreatePoint2d(twoprect2_len, twoprect2_wid))

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()

    #Create extrusion feature
    solid_profile = main.Profiles.AddForSolid()
    solid_profile2 = main2.Profiles.AddForSolid()

    ext_def1 = part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.CreateExtrudeDefinition(solid_profile, 20481) #20481 = join
    ext_def2 = part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.CreateExtrudeDefinition(solid_profile2, 20482) #20482 = cut

    ext_len = width #Length of extrusion, in cm
    ext_len2 = width

    ext_def1.SetDistanceExtent(ext_len, 20994) #20994 = negative direction
    ext_def2.SetDistanceExtent(ext_len2, 20994)

    part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.Add(ext_def1) #Add extrusion feature to object
    part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.Add(ext_def2)

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()

    #Create legs for table
    bot_surf = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8))

    leg_ext_len = 10

    circ_1 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(12,-12), 3)
    circ_2 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(length - 12,-12), 3)
    circ_3 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(12,-width + 12), 3)
    circ_4 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(length - 12,-width + 12), 3)

    leg_sld_prof = bot_surf.Profiles.AddForSolid()

    leg_ext_def = part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.CreateExtrudeDefinition(leg_sld_prof, 20481)

    leg_ext_def.SetDistanceExtent(leg_ext_len, 20993)

    part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.Add(leg_ext_def)

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()

    print("no. of surfaces = " + part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Count)

    #Create fillet feature
    edg1 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(2).Edges.Item(2) #Create edge objects
    edg2 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(2).Edges.Item(4)
    edg3 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(4).Edges.Item(2)
    edg4 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(4).Edges.Item(4)
    edg5 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(6).Edges.Item(2)
    edg6 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(6).Edges.Item(4)
    edg7 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8).Edges.Item(2)
    edg8 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8).Edges.Item(4)

    edg_coll_side1 = inv.TransientObjects.CreateEdgeCollection()#Create edge collections
    edg_coll_side2 = inv.TransientObjects.CreateEdgeCollection()

    side_fillet_def = part_comp_def.Features.FilletFeatures.CreateFilletDefinition()#Create fillet definition

    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg1)#Add edge objects to collection
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg2)
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg3)
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg4)

    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg5)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg6)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg7)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg8)

    side_fillet_def.AddConstantRadiusEdgeSet(edg_coll_side1, 4)#Create fillet feature
    side_fillet_def.AddConstantRadiusEdgeSet(edg_coll_side2, 8)

    part_comp_def.Features.FilletFeatures.Add(side_fillet_def)#Add fillet feature to object

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()

    

    # surf_test = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(1))
    # appearance = doc.AppearanceManager.Appearances.Item("Bamboo")
    # surf_test.Appearance = appearance

    

#Sample
createEndOrCoffeeTable(100, 100, 80, 0, 0)

I wrote this Autodesk Inventor API python code. I expect that if the code would run properly, it would create the table main geometry, extrude the main geometry, create and extrude the bottom surface geometry as legs, and fillet the selected edges. When I run the code, the terminal shows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Utility/Kuliah/Tugas/CAD-M/Tugas API python/InvAPITable.py", line 107, in <module>
    createEndOrCoffeeTable(100, 100, 80, 0, 0)
  File "d:/Utility/Kuliah/Tugas/CAD-M/Tugas API python/InvAPITable.py", line 67, in createEndOrCoffeeTable
    edg1 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(2).Edges.Item(2) #Create edge objects
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Item
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)

If I move the 'table legs' part after the 'fillet' part just like this
def createEndOrCoffeeTable(length, width, height, legType, color):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    #Create fillet feature
    edg1 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(2).Edges.Item(2) #Create edge objects
    edg2 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(2).Edges.Item(4)
    edg3 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(4).Edges.Item(2)
    edg4 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(4).Edges.Item(4)
    edg5 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(6).Edges.Item(2)
    edg6 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(6).Edges.Item(4)
    edg7 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8).Edges.Item(2)
    edg8 = part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8).Edges.Item(4)

    edg_coll_side1 = inv.TransientObjects.CreateEdgeCollection()#Create edge collections
    edg_coll_side2 = inv.TransientObjects.CreateEdgeCollection()

    side_fillet_def = part_comp_def.Features.FilletFeatures.CreateFilletDefinition()#Create fillet definition

    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg1)#Add edge objects to collection
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg2)
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg3)
    edg_coll_side1.Add(edg4)

    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg5)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg6)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg7)
    edg_coll_side2.Add(edg8)

    side_fillet_def.AddConstantRadiusEdgeSet(edg_coll_side1, 4)#Create fillet feature
    side_fillet_def.AddConstantRadiusEdgeSet(edg_coll_side2, 8)

    part_comp_def.Features.FilletFeatures.Add(side_fillet_def)#Add fillet feature to object

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()

    #Create legs for table
    bot_surf = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8))

    leg_ext_len = 10

    circ_1 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(12,-12), 3)
    circ_2 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(length - 12,-12), 3)
    circ_3 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(12,-width + 12), 3)
    circ_4 = bot_surf.SketchCircles.AddByCenterRadius(tg.CreatePoint2d(length - 12,-width + 12), 3)

    leg_sld_prof = bot_surf.Profiles.AddForSolid()

    leg_ext_def = part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.CreateExtrudeDefinition(leg_sld_prof, 20481)

    leg_ext_def.SetDistanceExtent(leg_ext_len, 20993)

    part_comp_def.Features.ExtrudeFeatures.Add(leg_ext_def)

    inv.ActiveView.GoHome()


    # surf_test = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(1))
    # appearance = doc.AppearanceManager.Appearances.Item("Bamboo")
    # surf_test.Appearance = appearance

    

#Sample
createEndOrCoffeeTable(100, 100, 80, 0, 0)

, the terminal instead shows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Utility/Kuliah/Tugas/CAD-M/Tugas API python/InvAPITable.py", line 109, in <module>
    createEndOrCoffeeTable(100, 100, 80, 0, 0)
  File "d:/Utility/Kuliah/Tugas/CAD-M/Tugas API python/InvAPITable.py", line 81, in createEndOrCoffeeTable
    bot_surf = part_comp_def.Sketches.Add(part_comp_def.SurfaceBodies.Item(1).Faces.Item(8))
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in Add
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Anyone know what's the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
